# Howto set "text" value for suds webservice object

Tags: python, web-services, suds

Suds seems to have problems parsing the following XSD:

```
<element name="quantity" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>Quantity of this item that's being ordered.</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <complexType>
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="int">
                <attribute name="unitOfMeasure" use="required">
                    <annotation>
                        <documentation>
                            Unit of measurement.

                            The attribute can have the 
                            following values: PCS - pieces
                            SEC- seconds BYT - bytes KB -
                            kilobytes
                        </documentation>
                    </annotation>
                    <simpleType>
                        <restriction base="string">
                            <enumeration value="PCS" />
                            <enumeration value="SEC" />
                            <enumeration value="BYT" />
                            <enumeration value="KB" />
                        </restriction>
                    </simpleType>
                </attribute>
            </extension>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

The XML is supposed to look like:

```
<ns0:quantity unitOfMeasure="PCS">1</ns:quantity>
```

Sadly, I can only set the attribute:

```
>>> c.factory.create('ns0:item.quantity')
(quantity){
   _unitOfMeasure = ""
 }
```

with no possibility to set the "text" value of the XML node.

I've tried creating the XML literally:

```
element = Element('ns0:quantity')
element.setText("1")
element.set('unitOfMeasure', "PCS")
```

and passing that as parameter.

This looks good in the debug logging (as `<ns0:quantity unitOfMeasure="PCS">1</ns0:quantity>`) but the actual request shows this value will be serialized as:

```
<ns0:quantity />
```

I'm getting lost here.
How can I submit this value properly?

I'm using suds 0.4

Comment: Don't use suds, try suds-jurko: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.6 which is a maintained fork of suds. If the problem still occurs there, we can check whether something can be subclassed / done to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Just found a temporary workaround.

The problem also occurs with suds-jurko.
While the pretty-format logging in suds.client shows the XML element,
the raw logging in `suds.transport.http` shows that the "plain" output fails to serialize the element.

By enabling `client.options.prettyxml = True` this issue is circumvented.